# What is the name of the design pattern where you chain method results of the same object?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've seen this design pattern and I can't remember the name:

```
class Number {
  private int myNumber;
  public Number(int arg) {this.myNumber = arg;}
  public Number add (int arg) {return new Number(myNumber + arg);}
  public Number subtract (int arg) {return new Number(myNumber - arg);}
}
```

So the way you use it is:

```
Object result = (new Number(1)).add(2).subtract(1).add(3);
```

The point being you can keep chaining the method results together.

My question is: **What is the name of the design pattern where you chain method results of the same object?**

Comment: Fluent interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard as [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). This makes harder to debug in some cases, the entire chain of actions may be considered a single statement so in my opinion: not such a good idea.

Comment: I don't agree with you. I use this pattern very much in building up complicated data configurations for regression tests and it served very well to keep the code clean. Used together with the Builder Pattern it also allows reuse very well. I think it is a great idea, if you use it right. Like most patterns.

Comment: By "harder to debug", are you referring to trying to debug with an IDE?

Comment: I fully agree. When you have 5 calls chained after each other and an exception is thrown ... have fun figuring the details. I think it doesn't come as surprise that the new version of IntelliJ added a special **debugger** just for fluent stream expressions. And beyond that, depending how the "fluent" is done, it might sometimes be a simple violation of the Law Of Demeter.

Comment: @GhostCat Do you know exception breakpoints? very effective! And IDE-ergonomic problems should never be a cause to write bad and unreadable code. And not using this pattern is missing a great opportunity.
And since you are always communicating with the same object, at least if you use it in the form I proposed, then you adhere quite good to the "law of demeter". Perhaps in an extra case we should look at the bad examples you have in mind.  Here I can not understand the problems you have with this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Just calling methods of a class in a chain does not qualify itself to be a pattern. Design patterns are documented at design level and those solutions are implementation independent. There will be patterns whose code and UML diagram will look similar but due to its different intent they represent implementations of different patterns (e.g. State and Strategy). But calling such a chain for building object with possibility of permutation combinations of many optional parameters, is seen in Builder pattern. Where original object is created with mandatory parameters and reconfigured by builder under its strict control as per the requirement of client without breaking encapsulation. "Effective Java: A Programming Language Guide" by Joshua Bloch has demonstrated effective usage of this kind of Builder pattern in the book.